# Fill only half of the container with a background color

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

[image]

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#child {
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```

The red box is the container and it's height is equal to its content - in this case 150px. What I'd like to achieve is to make the container height equal half the size of its content size.

**The effect that I want to achieve is to have the `background-color` fill half of the containers content.**

If this can be made in some other way than changing the container height - feel free to propose a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a linear gradient:

```css
#child {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, green 50%, white 0%); 
}
```

change `white` with body color or any color you want.

Source: [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/css-background-with-2-colors/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gradients` here.

Not sure if you want to keep the offset above the green div, but if so, you can also use `calc()` inside gradients :

- add a `margin-top: 75px` to the child
- set `background: linear-gradient(red calc(50% + 37px), transparent calc(50% + 37px))` on the parent

This way you don't have to fix any height. Will ease your responsive work afterwards!

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  background: linear-gradient(red 50%, transparent 50%);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#child {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child">
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
    content!<br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign a `height` to the `container` and set `height: 200%;` for the `child`, like this to make sure the `container` has half the `height` of the `child`:

```
#container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: 100% 50%;
}

#child {
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 200%;
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly the way you want to do this, but the result is the same. Maybe it'll help you.

You can make a pseudo element, which has half the height of the `container` and give it a `height 50%;`. This way you get a different `background-color` for half of the `container` s `height`.

```css
#container {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}

#child {
  background-color: green;
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  opacity: .5;
  top: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
}

div#container:after {
  content: " Different Color! ";
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="child"></div>
</div>
```